# Python requests API dealing with different format

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I'll try to be very straight, how to format this output?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'referer': 'https://www.giga.com.vc/padaria?initialMap=c&initialQuery=padaria&map=category-1&page=2',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'x-request-id': '24af6e1c94114c5488296d68ef93daf2',
    'x-vtex-cache-status': 'EXPIRED',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36'
}

req = requests.get(f'https://www.giga.com.vc/padaria?initialMap=c&initialQuery=padaria&map=category-1&page=1', headers=headers)
#     print(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')

soup_script = soup.find_all('script')[14].text
print(soup_script)
```

Received output:

```
{"Product:sp-139989":{"cacheId":"sp-139989","productId":"139989","description":"Bolinho sabor Duplo Chocolate Bauducco é irresistível. Sua Fórmula é enriquecida com vitaminas e cálcio, ótimo para ser levado na lancheira dos pequenos, na bolsa ou na mochila. O Sabor Baunilha e Morango é a perfeita combinação entre massa de baunilha e recheio de morango, um bolinho fofinho e delicioso!","productName":"Bolinho sabor Baunilha e Morango Bauducco 40G","productReference":"223184","linkText":"mini-bolo-de-baunilha-e-morango-bauducco-40g","bra..
```

Desired output:
productId, productName, description, ean, price, specificationGroups, and stuffs that I can easily retrieve through the code.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll find the *json* module very helpful. Use its *loads()* function. That will give you a Python dictionary. Go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

# set to show all columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

headers = {
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'referer': 'https://www.giga.com.vc/padaria?initialMap=c&initialQuery=padaria&map=category-1&page=2',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'x-request-id': '24af6e1c94114c5488296d68ef93daf2',
    'x-vtex-cache-status': 'EXPIRED',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36'
}

req = requests.get(f'https://www.giga.com.vc/padaria?initialMap=c&initialQuery=padaria&map=category-1&page=1', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')

soup_script = soup.find_all('script')[14].text
data = json.loads(soup_script)

# save raw data to file
with open("data.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

---

```
# read raw data from file 
with open("data.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

---

```
# cleanup raw data
re_pattern_key_filter = r'sp-\d{6}'
re_pattern_key_rename = r'(.*?)(sp-\d{6})(.*?)$'

# filter out trash data and cleanup keys in dictionary
raw_target_data = [(re.sub(re_pattern_key_rename, r'\2', key), value) for key, value in data.items() if re.search(re_pattern_key_filter, key)]

# merge data to product_id nested dict
raw_product_id_data = {}
for key, value in raw_target_data:
    raw_product_id_data.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

# merge data to product_id dict
product_data = {}
for key, value in raw_product_id_data.items():
    product_data[key] = [{k: v for d in value for k, v in d.items()}]

# create dataframe for each product and add to list
all_dfs = []
for k, v in  product_data.items():
    df = pd.json_normalize(v)
    all_dfs.append(df)

# merge product dataframes into one
df = pd.concat(all_dfs).reset_index(drop=True)

df.head()
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Thank you, just to know, there's some way to take the productId and other stuffs?
When I do this it seems like I just can access one produt:
data = json.loads(soup_script)["Product:sp-139989"]
print(soup_script)

Comment: Hi, I am working on that.

Comment: Nice of you! I don't want you to lose a lot of your time, you might be busy as well.

If it can help you, I started to try something like this:

data2 = json.loads(soup_script)
for k, v in data2.items():
    try:
        product_id = v['productId']
    except:
        product_id = 'None'

    print(product_id)

Comment: @renan, please take a look at the updated code.

Comment: Awesome!! You really took everything! Just a little detail, the only thing that I noticed this line have disappeared:
{'name': 'CX', 'originalName': 'CX', 'values': {'type': 'json', 'json': ['112']}
I need this "112" value because it is the size of the box, it still exists here:
for key, value in raw_product_id_data.items():
    print(value)
but after this product_data[key] = [{k: v for d in value for k, v in d.items()}] I can't see anymore, any guess?